# Eclipse editor issues when working with ADT and Android SDK

Tags: android, eclipse

I hope you can put up with me and my questions. I really appreciate it if anybody can answer them. Well, here goes everything.

1st: I am using Eclipse 3.6,2 helios and I am learning Andriod development through Lynda.com videos. I am stuck on episode 2.4.

2nd: When I am in the visual editor (You can access it in the Res Folder > Layout Folder), I drag and drop the button icon.

3rd: This is where the problem starts:

In the java file, I try to reference to the UI components but no go. Instead of getting
    `Button b = findViewById(R.id.button);`

in the java file I get this:

`Button b = findViewById(R.id.menu_settings);`

Also I cant use `setOnClickListener` method.

I am using the latest ADT plugin and Android SDK.
Please help, I really want to learn Android development.
I aslo cant get a reference to UI components.

Comment: Maybe your R.java isn't updated.Try rebuilding the project. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487263/r-java-file-not-updating-with-ui-elements-id

Comment: I do not understand why you are using `R.id.menu_settings` instead of `R.id.button` ?

Comment: Check if your button has an attribute like android:id="@+id/button" - if it doesn't, you won't be able to find it by using findViewById.
What error do you get when you're trying to call setOnClickListener?

Comment: What do you mean " Instead of getting Button b = findViewById(R.id.button); in the java file I get this: Button b = findViewById(R.id.menu_settings);"  Do you mean that when you tried to type ".button", the only choice was "menu_settings"?

Comment: @Simon,  Yes I only get the choice "menu_settings"

Comment: @ Darwind Yes it does. The error I get when I use setOnClickListener is it doesnt reconginize it. It says Identifier expected after this token.

Answer (score 0):

Check how you've named your packages in Eclipse and how they are referenced in your manifest file. For example, if you have this in your manifest file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.mycompany.android.myapp"
  android:versionCode="3"
  android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard"
  android:versionName="1.0.2">
```

And you have a class in package com.mycompany.android.myapp.ui then you will probably have to import com.mycompany.android.myapp.R

In other words, you may have a 'root' package and classes in that package should be able to access R references without an import but other packages will have to import it.
Also, new references in the R file won't be visible until you build the project.

Comment: Thanks guys. THANKS TO ALL WHO READ MY QUESTIONS!! THANKS FOR YOUR ADVICE!! I LOVE YOU ALL!!! :)

Answer (score 0):

in Res>Layout>activity_main.xml

instead of Graphical Layout change tab to activity_main.xml.

in xml code find this

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1" ==> make sure id assigned
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" />
```

if id was set, try to clean project (Eclipse > Project > Clean ...)

and also make sure in your java file you did not imported this

```
import android.R; //delete this!
```

then you can use:

```
Button BT= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
```